# Jenkins Multibranch pipeline job rate limit

Tags: authentication, jenkins, github-api, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a multibranch Jenkins pipeline job on Windows to detect new branches, and in this case, push feature branch packages to an internal nuget server. 
The source is held in Github and the rate limit of 60 calls/hour is reported and the job sleeps and the delay can be too long, so the developers would be just as well deploying the packages manually. I've set up ssh auth between Jenkins and Github, and for other jobs ssh works fine, but the help on the multibranch credentials item says

> Note that only "username with password" credentials are supported. Existing credentials of other kinds will be filtered out. This is because jenkins exercises GitHub API, and this last one does not support other ways of authentication.

When I add my username and password as credentials it connects but as I've said, I'm limit to 60 calls/hour, authenticated API calls would have a rate limit of 5000 calls/hour, if I have to use username/password, how do I connect to get the higher rate?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the cause here and will post in case anyone else runs into a similar problem, my github account had been flagged, so the rate limit was 60 calls/hour regardless of anything else I did. Sorted with github support and now working as expected.